# Sorting a subset and/or maintaining file order within ggplot facets

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I'm creating a forest plot of effect sizes (denoted as `or`), faceted by their type (`X` or `Y`), using `ggplot2`.

I would like for the first line of each facet to be the summary effect size (`cite=='Summary'`) for that facet, followed by a row per study, sorted by effect size (I don't particularly care if it's ascending or descending). Although I can easily create a dataframe corresponding to this, I can't seem to get it to plot in order in both facets without sorting the summary effect size too.

Please assume that there are too many datapoints to manually specify the order in which they should appear- below is a minimally representative subsample.

```
cite <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","B","A"))
or  <- c(8.132075,3.475255,5.727273,4.334704,4.009901) 
lowerCI <- c(4.6841118,1.5059889,-0.5582456,2.3612416,-2.6439191)
upperCI <- c(11.580039,5.444521,12.012791,6.308167,10.663721)
type <- as.factor(c("X","X","X","Y","Y"))

df <- data.frame(cite, or, lowerCI, upperCI, type) 

df <- df[order(df$type, -xtfrm(df$or)), ] # Sorting within type by or
```

Adding rows for summaries to the end of the dataset so they're unsorted:

```
X.row <- list(cite="Summary",or=3.506705,lowerCI=1.5375528,upperCI=5.475857,type="X")
df[nrow(df) + 1, names(X.row)] <- X.row
Y.row <- list(cite="Summary",or=4.332824,lowerCI=2.3594369,upperCI=6.306212,type="Y")
df[nrow(df) + 1, names(Y.row)] <- Y.row
```

Using code to maintain file order based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402242/keep-same-order-as-in-data-files-when-using-ggplot):

```
df <- transform(df,cite=factor(cite,levels=unique(cite)))
```

Plotting attempt:

```
plot<-ggplot(data=df, aes(y=cite, x=or, xmin=lowerCI, xmax=upperCI, shape = type)) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size=2)+
  geom_errorbarh(height=.1)+
  geom_point(data=subset(df,cite=='Summary'), color='black', size=5)+
  facet_grid(type~., scales= 'free', space='free')+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=levels(df$cite),
               labels=c(levels(df$cite)[1:3], expression(italic("Summary Effect"))))
```

Results:
[image: Attempt 1]

The problem is that the first facet, but not the second facet, is appropriately sorted. So I tried an alternative suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013753/conditional-formatting-of-axis-text-in-faceted-ggplot):

```
Xdat<-subset(df, type=="X") 
Ydat<-subset(df, type=="Y")
Xdat <- transform(Xdat,cite=factor(cite,levels=unique(cite)))
Ydat <- transform(Ydat,cite=factor(cite,levels=unique(cite)))

plot2<-ggplot(mapping=aes(y=cite, x=or, xmin=lowerCI, xmax=upperCI, shape = type)) +
  geom_point(data=Xdat,color = 'black', size=2)+
  geom_point(data=subset(Xdat,cite=='Summary'), color='black', size=7)+
  geom_errorbarh(data=Xdat,height=.1)+
  geom_point(data=Ydat,color = 'black', size=2)+
  geom_point(data=subset(Ydat,cite=='Summary'), color='black', size=7)+
  geom_errorbarh(data=Ydat,height=.1)+
  facet_grid(type~., scales= 'free', space='free')+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=levels(df$cite),
               labels=c(levels(df$cite)[1:3], expression(italic("Summary Effect"))))
```

This yields the same result. Any ideas?

ETA: I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064007/factor-order-within-faceted-dotplot-using-ggplot2) as recommended, and it maintains the sorting, but I'm now unable to get y-axis labels to display properly.

Creating the unique cite variable:

```
df$type <- factor(df$type, levels = c("X","Y"))
df$cite.type <- with(df, paste(cite, type, sep = "_")) 
df$cite.type <- as.factor(df$cite.type)
df <- transform(df,cite.type=factor(cite.type,levels=unique(cite.type)))
df <- transform(df,cite=factor(cite,levels=unique(cite)))
```

Plotting (note that I cannot retain the `y=reorder(cite.type,or)` part because that would shift the summary effects:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(y=cite.type, x=or, xmin=lowerCI, xmax=upperCI, shape = type)) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size=2)+
  geom_errorbarh(height=.1)+
  geom_point(data=subset(df,cite=='Summary'), color='black', size=5)+
  facet_grid(type~., scales= 'free', space='free')+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=levels(df$cite.type),
               labels=c(levels(df$cite)[1:3], expression(italic("Summary Effect"))))
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Note that it's now sorted appropriately but the y axis labels are only printed once per cite.

Comment: just get rid of `scales = "free"`?

Comment: Something [like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064007/factor-order-within-faceted-dotplot-using-ggplot2)

Comment: `scales = "free"` is necessary to remove citations that are included in one type but not the other. The solution posted by @RomanLuštrik looks promising but it ends up only printing one instance of each cite label in the axes (i.e., they aren't repeated across facets).